# How to set OrbitalControls initial position?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've been messing around with react-three-fiber and really liked the OrbitControls element which lets you control the camera by dragging the mouse around.

My doubt is if there's a way to control the initial position/perspective of the element.

I'm creating a demo and I'm using a a plane to simulate the ground. It looks fine when seen from above but on the default position it becomes invisible, like looking a sheet of paper horizontally.

I tried to mess around with some properties like position and minPolarAngle but couldn't observe any difference. Any one out there could help on this one?

```
      <Canvas>
        <OrbitControls position={[10, -40, 0]} /> // 'position' doesn't seem to work
        <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />

        <Suspense fallback={"...Loading"}>
          <Stars />
          <Box/>
          <Ground />
        </Suspense>

      </Canvas>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `React-three-fiber` but since `OrbitControls` just controls the camera of your scene, can't you just define a starting position for the camera?

Comment: I gave up on finding the correct prop and just went with a combination of `useThree(state=>state.camera)` and `useEffect(()=>{camera.position.set(10,-40,0)},[camera])`. This sets initial position. Then the `target` prop sets the lookAt vector.

Answer (score 8):

`OrbitControls` will use the existing camera and respect its initial position*, so you don't need to do anything specialized; just specify the `camera` prop on `Canvas`.

*but not its initial *rotation*. `OrbitControls` will instantly overwrite any calls to `camera.lookAt`. In that case, specify a `target` (defaults to [0,0,0]).

```
<Canvas camera={{ fov: 45, position: [10, -40, 0] }}>
  <OrbitControls target={[10, 0, 0]} />
</Canvas>
```